# How to add Javascript into Django?

Tags: django

I recently got my static files working for my project directory. I wrote a separate file with a javascript function called my function. I have a  in html that calls a function in my javascript, but chrome is returning a function is not defined error. 
Does anyone know how to resolve this?

```html
{% load static %}
{% block content%}
  <h1 id="change" onclick="myFunction()"> hi! </h1>
{% endblock %}
```

```html
function myFunction(){
    var count = 0;
    console.log(count);
}
```

Chrome Error
(index):55 Uncaught ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined
    at HTMLHeadingElement.onclick ((index):55)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tag `{% load static %}` doesn't create script tags for you; you still need to define them:

```
{% load static %}

{% block content%}
  <h1 id="change" onclick="myFunction()"> hi! </h1>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'someFile.js' %}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: thank you so much 2 hours of debugging solved with this!